# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|x_{n}\|=\|x\|$ and and other conditions to imply $\lbrace x_{n} \rbrace \to x$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits

Let $X$ be a metric space with inner product space. Suppose that there is a sequence, $ \lbrace x_{n} \rbrace $,  in $X$ such $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|x_{n}\|=\|x\|$ and such $\lbrace \langle x_{n}, y \rangle \rbrace \to \langle x,y \rangle$ for every $y \in X$. Then $\lbrace x_{n} \rbrace \to x$.

As $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|x_{n}\|=\|x\|$ we got that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|x_{n}-x\|=0$ and I somehow get to have that $\lim_{n \to \infty}|x_{n}-x|=0$ still don't know how to properly apply a triangle inequality here or maybe Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: What is “a metric space with inner product space”?

Comment: There is a function $\langle , \rangle: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies certain axioms

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Comment: this $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\|x_{n}\|=\|x\|\implies\lim_{n \to \infty}\|x_{n}-x\|=0$$ is false, one doesnt follow from the other. The RHS is **the definition** of what the notation $\{x_n\}\to x$ means, what you need to prove using the weak convergence

Answer (score 1):

HINT: remember that

$$
\|a-b\|^2=\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2-\langle a,b \rangle-\langle b,a \rangle
$$

Comment: How can this hint can be thinked in the original problem? @Masacroso

Answer (score 0):

choose a=x_n and b=x, and remember that y is any point in X so you can choose it to be x. So...